# Is it possible to corrupt a git repository with control of a remote?

Tags: git, version-control

So I'm trying to understand ways in which a malicious actor can corrupt a git repository.

For instance, let's say there's an untrusted server that you ssh into that has a remote that you use. Is it possible that a malicious actor can corrupt a git repository in such a way that when I pull from it, I'll have some kind of data loss?

I am assuming that because of integrity checks, the answer is no, but I'm ideally looking for mechanisms/checks that the git client does to protect the integrity of the repo.

Comment: Have you tried it out? You can make remotes on your local machine to cut out any ssh/network issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git usually does not perform an fsck on fetch, so it is possible to fetch corrupt data (like corrupt or invalid commit or tag objects) without noticing.  It's also possible that an untrusted remote can provide valid but malicious data, such as data that tries to overwrite the `.git` directory due to case-insensitivity issues; these are also rejected by `git fsck`.

Setting `fetch.fsckObjects` to `true` will catch all of these cases.  That doesn't, however, prevent people from inserting valid objects that contain malicious code or data that will exploit your working environment, but it should reject cases that are trying to exploit Git itself.  Most hosting providers set `receive.fsckObjects` so that they reject all of these exploits before they're accepted into the repo, as well as just general corrupt data.

If you're needing to push to an untrusted server, you may choose to set `fetch.fsckObjects` and use commit signing, which will prevent others from tampering with the actual objects.  It won't, however, prevent people from rolling back refs or otherwise modifying them.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to understand. Can you also help me understand how many of these issues will not be noticeable by a `git diff <old>..<new>` ?

Comment: Any of the errors that are checkable by `git fsck` may not be noticed immediately.  You also might not notice rolled back refs if you don't notice missing code.  If it's valid but malicious code, you'd notice that in a diff.